# How to make specific table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Given `x <- c('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC')` and a number `n`,
I want to make a table:

```
type   file      path_to_file
typeA  typeA_1   /home/lynnyi/typeA/typeA_1.txt
typeA  typeA_2   /home/lynnyi/typeA/typeA_2.txt
...
typeA  typeA_n   /home/lynnyi/typeA/typeA_3.txt
typeB  typeB_1   /home/lynnyi/typeB/typeB_1.txt
...
typeB  typeB_n   /home/lynnyi/typeB/typeB_1.txt
typeC  typeC_1   /home/lynnyi/typeC/typeB_1.txt
...
typeC  typeC_n   /home/lynnyi/typeC/typeB_1.txt
```

I know how to use various sapplys to get the value of each of the columns, i.e. `['typeA_1',...,'typeA_n',.......,'typeC_n']`  and `['/home/lynnyi/typeA/typeA_1.txt', .... ... , '/home/lynnyi/typeC/typeC_n.txt']`

But then I lose the ability to join them based in type and num...

How do I have them all in one table / data frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n is same for all types, this can be done as follows:

```
x <- c('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC')
n <- 10

types <- sort(rep(x, 10))
files <- paste(types, rep(1:n, 3), sep = "_")
paths <- paste("/homme/lynnyi", types, paste0(files, ".txt"), sep = "/")

data <- cbind(types, files, paths)
```